# Cannot import getSignInClient method in Android Studio 4.2.2

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase-authentication

In my Class that extends AppCompatActivity

```
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.identity.Identity.getSignInClient;
```

cannot resolve symbol getSignInClient that appears in red.
In Gradle is put

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.1.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
```

So, the code has an error on this line

```
oneTapClient = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Identity.getSignInClient(this);
```

oneTapClient is declare as follows:

```
private SignInClient oneTapClient;
```

where is the mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same issue before

check your imports and remove
 `import android.provider.ContactsContract;` this

and use the following

```
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.identity.Identity;

oneTapClient = Identity.getSignInClient(this);
```

or just use it like this

```
 oneTapClient = com.google.android.gms.auth.api.identity.Identity.getSignInClient(this);
```